# Mac OS X - Accept self-signed multi domain SSL Certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I've got a self-signed certificate for multiple domains (let's say my.foo.bar.com & yours.foo.bar.com) that I've imported using Keychain Access but Chrome will still not accept it, prompting me for verification at the beginning of each browsing session **per domain**.

The Certificate was generated using the x509v3 *subject alternative name* extension to validate multiple domains. If I navigate to the site *before* I import the certificate, I get a different warning message than *after* importing. Attached below is an image of the two errors (with the top being the error before imported)

[image]

Is there any way to accept a self-signed multi-domain certificate? I only get warnings in Chrome, btw. FF and Safari work great (except those browsers suck ;) )

UPDATE: I tried generating the cert both with the openssl cli and the [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) GUI

Comment: How exactly did you generate your cert? Why subject key identifiers? Did you mean subject alternative names?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Yes to subject alternative names. I tried generating both with the openssl CLI tools and xca (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/)

Comment: Have you made sure your SANs are of DNS type? (xca gives a choice between URI, DNS and IP at least, as far as I remember)

Comment: "*(with the top being the error before imported)*" That's probably the other way around.

Comment: Nope, top is definitely before import. Yeah, SANs are listed as DNS. 

Ideally, I'd like to specify the SANs as *, *.*, etc. to support unlimited subdomains. All of this is just for a testing dev box where we use multiple nested subdomains (which I hate, but what can you do)

Comment: You can't have just `*` as a name.

Comment: Bummer, though I'm not surprised. I also tried *.com, as well as a specific & subdomains  (CN:bar.com, SANs: DNS:my.foo.bar.com, DNS:yours.foo.bar.com) and still no love. 

Is it possible that Chrome just has no love for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use too broad a wildcard (`*` or `*.com`).

The specifications ([RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) and [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)) talk about "*left-most*" labels, which implies there should be more than one label:

> ```
>  1.  The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
>      which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
>      left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net).
>
>  2.  If the wildcard character is the only character of the left-most
>      label in the presented identifier, the client SHOULD NOT compare
>      against anything but the left-most label of the reference
>      identifier (e.g., *.example.com would match foo.example.com but
>      not bar.foo.example.com or example.com).
> ```

I'm not sure whether there's a specification to say how many minimum labels there should be, but the [Chromium code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/cert/x509_certificate.cc?revision=191450#l555) indicates that there must be at least 2 dots:

> We required at least 3 components (i.e. 2 dots) as a basic protection
> against too-broad wild-carding.

This is indeed to prevent too broad cases like `*.com`. This may seem inconvenient, but CAs make mistakes once in a while, and having a measure to prevent a potential rogue cert issued to `*.com` to work isn't necessarily a bad thing.
If I remember correctly, some implementations go further than this and have a list domains that would be too broad for second-level domains too (e.g. `.co.uk`).

Regarding your second example: "*CN:bar.com, SANs: DNS:my.foo.bar.com, DNS:yours.foo.bar.com*". This certificate should be valid for `my.foo.bar.com` and `yours.foo.bar.com` but not `bar.com`. The CN is only a fallback solution when no SANs are present. If there are any SANs, the CN should be ignored (although some implementations will be more tolerant).

Comment: Ah, great answer! I had no idea about the CN being a fallback for no SANs. 

Thanks for all the back and forth. I'll check it out here in a few and accept once I get it working.

Comment: Alas, still no love. So I've got the CN set to *.example.com, with SANs to "DNS:*.example.com, DNS:*.*.example.com" and when I hit foo.bar.example.com it warns that it's identified as *.example.com. Do I need to **not** supply a CN?

Comment: I guess `.example.com` is `*.example.com` the typo is due to the comment formatting. You can only use one wildcard: the left-most label. If you want something for `foo.bar.example.com`, try `*.bar.example.com` (or `foo.bar.example.com` directly, of course).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't catch the SO formatting taking out my asterisks. Ah, that's probably my issue then. The single wildcard is what's sinking me I'll bet. Okay, I'll give it another shot here in a sec

Comment: Still working out a few quirks, but it does appear the multiple wildcards were the issues. Would you mind updating your answer to include that and I'll accept it? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sure, although it's already in the RFC 6125 link I posted (for the right section).